# How can I use different facebook account to sign in a game on iphone?

Tags: iphone, games, facebook

I used a facebook account to sign in a game on my iphone ( the game is "top eleven"). Now I want to change the account and use another one because I have more friends in 2nd account.
Already used 2nd account's username and password in setting but didn't work, even deleted facebook app and installed it again and signed in with 2nd one but when I open the game it runs with 1st one.
how can I solve this problem ?
thanks

Comment: Doesn’t this depend almost entirely on the app in question being named? We can all speculate about  His, but it’s really up to the app developer how the leverage a federated log in.

Answer (score 6):

It’s because you are also signed in on Facebook in Safari browser.
iPhone first looks for Facebook login in safari before looking for it in the Facebook app.

Log out of Facebook in Safari browser. 
The game will then use your Facebook app to determine which account to use for login

Comment: Far from obvious, but it worked!! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the Facebook login in the app itself. There should be Settings somewhere within the game, and the option to "Log Out" of Facebook. Once you have logged out, you will need to link it to your 2nd Facebook account by logging into it - again - within the app itself.

Answer (score 1):

Or you have to delete the app, install it again and sign in with your Facebook Account.